can't use pipewire - failed to initialize PW context
I'm trying to run Bliss OS through QEMU following this guide, and it works well. Now, I'm attempting to run it using virt-manager. After configuring the VM settings, I encounter the following error:
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2024-08-25T13:58:29.563176Z qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to initialize PW context

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1379, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2024-08-25T13:58:29.563176Z qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to initialize PW context

I tried to google it and found that this might be related to permission issues. I modified the user and group settings in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf:
user = "reyuki"
group = "reyuki"

However, the error persists. I also tried creating a new QEMU/KVM user session on virt-manager, but the error remains unchanged.
I verified that the PipeWire service is running:
[hemlo@ASUS ~]$  systemctl --user status pipewire*
● pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-08-25 18:33:28 WIB; 2h 15min ago
 Invocation: a266a0a7714f4cec9d9edadd13b93e66
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire-pulse.socket
   Main PID: 755 (pipewire-pulse)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 37453)
     Memory: 9.3M (peak: 17.7M)
        CPU: 13.705s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire-pulse.service
             └─755 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse

Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS systemd[743]: Started PipeWire PulseAudio.
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire-pulse[755]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire-pulse[755]: mod.rt: RTKit does not give us MaxRealtimePriority, using 1
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire-pulse[755]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire-pulse[755]: mod.rt: RTKit does not give us MinNiceLevel, using 0
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire-pulse[755]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire-pulse[755]: mod.rt: RTKit does not give us RTTimeUSecMax, using -1

● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-08-25 18:33:28 WIB; 2h 15min ago
 Invocation: 2a5b383e3e9545f6a57443f40e101f2b
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 753 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 37453)
     Memory: 7.4M (peak: 10M)
        CPU: 13.729s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─753 /usr/bin/pipewire

Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS systemd[743]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire[753]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire[753]: mod.rt: RTKit does not give us MaxRealtimePriority, using 1
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire[753]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire[753]: mod.rt: RTKit does not give us MinNiceLevel, using 0
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire[753]: mod.rt: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS pipewire[753]: mod.rt: RTKit does not give us RTTimeUSecMax, using -1

● pipewire-pulse.socket - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-08-25 18:33:28 WIB; 2h 15min ago
 Invocation: 9ab30b1f194946f68d2dd6e0a8e1c54b
   Triggers: ● pipewire-pulse.service
     Listen: /run/user/1000/pulse/native (Stream)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/pipewire-pulse.socket

Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS systemd[743]: Listening on PipeWire PulseAudio.

● pipewire.socket - PipeWire Multimedia System Sockets
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-08-25 18:33:28 WIB; 2h 15min ago
 Invocation: 772c6b34a94b42a3b8310e67a3a65851
   Triggers: ● pipewire.service
     Listen: /run/user/1000/pipewire-0 (Stream)
             /run/user/1000/pipewire-0-manager (Stream)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/pipewire.socket

Aug 25 18:33:28 ASUS systemd[743]: Listening on PipeWire Multimedia System Sockets.

Here's the VM settings in xml format:
<domain xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0" type="kvm">
  <name>Android_BlissOS</name>
  <uuid>f4e227f8-f5ac-4d7b-9df9-d861303ef048</uuid>
  <memory unit="KiB">1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-i440fx-9.0">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state="off"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on"/>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/home/reyuki/experiments/virtual-machine/blissOS/Bliss11.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="hda" bus="ide"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="piix3-uhci">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pci-root"/>
    <controller type="ide" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <sound model="ac97">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <audio id="1" type="none"/>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value="-enable-kvm"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-M"/>
    <qemu:arg value="q35"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-m"/>
    <qemu:arg value="4096"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-smp"/>
    <qemu:arg value="4"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-cpu"/>
    <qemu:arg value="host"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-bios"/>
    <qemu:arg value="/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF.fd"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-usb"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="virtio-tablet"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="virtio-keyboard"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="qemu-xhci,id=xhci"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-machine"/>
    <qemu:arg value="vmport=off"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="virtio-vga-gl"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-display"/>
    <qemu:arg value="sdl,gl=on"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-audiodev"/>
    <qemu:arg value="pipewire,id=snd0"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="AC97,audiodev=snd0"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-net"/>
    <qemu:arg value="nic,model=virtio-net-pci"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-net"/>
    <qemu:arg value="user,hostfwd=tcp::4444-:5555"/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>

What could be the underlying issue, and how can I resolve it? Thanks in advance for your help.
